# how to get the correct time with php

Tags: php

i am trying to get the correct time with php 
not the one that the user's computer gives is there a function that gives the correct "GMT" time as an example .

Comment: You can set your timezone before you can get the correct date and time. http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: maybe because i was using a local server thats why i was getting my computer's time thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP gets the server date, not the user computer date.

If you need to get a different date timezone then you need set the timezone to your desired.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

like:

```
$tz = 'Europe/London';
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y, H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want GMT time, you can use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead of [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). For example,

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Output (for a server in Europe)

```
2019-02-04 03:34:05 
2019-02-04 02:34:05
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PR0iK)

Answer (score -1):

You will be getting the server time only, not the computer time

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); //timezone format
echo $now->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"); // Server time
```

Comment: This is a bad practice. Please refer at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)